# Vector template argument invalid

Tags: c++

I have the following code,

```
typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   node * left;
   node * right;
}node;

#include <vector>
std::vector<node*> findValue(node * node, int value, std::vector<node*> parents) {...}
```

But I'm getting the compile error:

error: template argument 1 is invalid

```
 std::vector<node*> findValue(node * node, int value, std::vector<node*> parents) {
                                                                   ^
```

How do I correctly declare an function argument of a vector of node pointers?

Comment: Not the fix but, you needn't use the c style declaration of the struct, Just do `struct node`, with nothing but the semi colon after `}`

Comment: `node * node` can only end badly. Might even be your griefer. Edit. Yup. That's the boy. By the time you hit the `vector<node*>` definition, `node` is the name of a variable, not a type.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
std::vector<node*> findValue(node * node, int value, std::vector<node*> parents)
```

`node * node` redefines the identifier `node` as a variable. When the compiler parses `std::vector<node*> parents`, node is no longer a type that can be used in a template expansion.

## Solution

Be careful when reusing names.

```
std::vector<node*> findValue(node * notnode, int value, std::vector<node*> parents)
```

`notnode` is an example that solves the problem. A more descriptive name is highly recommended.